# How to bind gateway to a specific namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have the following scenario: 
[image]

- When the user **A** enter the address foo.example1.example.com in the
  browser, then it should call the service **FOO** in the namespace
  **example1**.
- When the user **B** enter the address foo.example1.example.com in the
  browser, then it should call the service **FOO** in the namespace
  **example2**.

I am using istio, the question is, how to configure the gateway, that is bind specific to a namespace:

Look at an example of istio gateway configuration:

```
  $ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
  apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
  kind: Gateway
  metadata:
    name: ns_example1
  spec:
    selector:
      istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
    servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
      - "example1.example.com"
  EOF
```

When I would deploy the gateway, then it will apply to current namespace but I would like to specify a namespace.

How to assign a gateway to specific namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [link](https://istiobyexample.dev/secure-ingress/) should answer your question.

There is many things You won't need, but there is idea You want to apply to your istio cluster.

So You need 1 gateway and 2 virtual services.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: foocorp-gateway
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http-example1
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "example1.example.com"
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http-example2
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "example2.example.com"
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: example1
  namespace: ex1
spec:
  hosts:
  - "example1.example.com"
  gateways:
  - foocorp-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: example1.ex1.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: example2
  namespace: ex2
spec:
  hosts:
  - "example2.example.com"
  gateways:
  - foocorp-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: example2.ex2.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

**EDIT**

You can create gateway in namespace ex1 and ex2,  then just change gateway field in virtual service and it should work.

Remember to add namespace/gateway, not only gateway name, like [there](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/).

```
gateways:
  - some-config-namespace/gateway-name
```

Let me know if that help You.

Comment: So it is not possible to setup 2 gateways in my case?

Comment: @zero_coding I answered your question, check EDIT.